# email body appears multiple times

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send a small batch of emails in a loop using PHP mail(). The script to send the emails works fine. There is, however, a slight glitch. Whilst the recipients all receive only one email, the first person on the list receives the email body ($MESSAGE_BODY) once, the second person gets the body twice and the third person gets it 3 times (and on it goes). I cannot for the life of me work out why it's doing it.

The form from which the emails are sent is:

```
<p>Message Text:
<br />
<textarea name="thebody" id="thebody" cols="65" rows="12"><?php echo $row_email['emailtext'];?></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace( 'thebody' );</script>
</p>
<table >
<tr>
<th>Site</th>
<th>Email Address</th>
<th colspan="2">Email Now?</th>
</tr>
<?php  
$b = 0;
$q = 1;
while ($row_selfdo = mysql_fetch_assoc($selfdo)) {  ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row_seldo[‘sitename’];?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="emailto[]" style="font-size:9px;" size="20" value="<?php echo $row_selfdo['eaddress']; ?>"/></td>

<td valign="middle">Yes:<input type="radio" name="emailnow[<?php echo $b;?>]" value="Yes" <?php if (isset($mailed) && ($mailed=="Not Yet")) { echo ""; } else echo "disabled='disabled'"; ?> /></td>

<td>No:<input name="emailnow[<?php echo $b;?>]" type="radio" value="No" checked="checked"  <?php if (isset($mailed) && ($mailed=="Not Yet")) { echo ""; } else echo "disabled='disabled'"; ?>? /></td>

</tr>
<?php $b++; $q++; }  ?>
</table>
```

And here's the script to send the mail

```
$numb = count($_POST['emailto']);
$num = $numb -1;
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$thisrecipient = $_POST['emailto'];
$sendtothemnow = $_POST['emailnow'];

for ($a=0;$a<=$num;$a++) {

$emailthemnow = $sendtothemnow[$a];


if ((isset($emailthemnow))&&(($emailthemnow)=="Yes")) {

$recipient = $thisrecipient[$a];
$ToEmail = $recipient; 
$EmailSubject = $subject; 
$mailheader = 'From: me@mydomain.com'."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= 'Reply-To: me@mydomain.com'."\r\n";
$mailheader .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$mailheader .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= '<p>'.$_POST['thebody'].'</p>';
$MESSAGE_BODY .= '<p>Kind Regards</p>';
$MESSAGE_BODY .= '<p>The Environment Team</p>';
$MESSAGE_BODY .= 'email footer bits here ';
$MESSAGE_BODY .='<p style="color:#0C0;">Please consider the environment - do you really need to print this email?';

$MESSAGE_BODY=wordwrap($MESSAGE_BODY,70);

$mailsent=  mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Not Sent");

    if($mailsent){
    //update a table to record date email was sent
    }
}//end email send loop
```

Any suggestions??

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your first line where you use the message body, set it instead of appending it:

```
$MESSAGE_BODY = '<p>'.$_POST['thebody'].'</p>';
```

(The dot has been removed)

Comment: So simple, works like a charm, thanks for such a quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Only change the variable name which have conflict.

```
if ((isset($emailthemnow))&&(($emailthemnow)=="Yes")) {
$recipient = $thisrecipient[$a];
$ToEmail = $recipient; 
$EmailSubject = $subject; 
$mailheader = 'From: me@mydomain.com'."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= 'Reply-To: me@mydomain.com'."\r\n";
$mailheader .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$mailheader .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= '<p>'.$_POST['thebody'].'</p>';
$MESSAGE_BODY .= '<p>Kind Regards</p>';
$MESSAGE_BODY .= '<p>The Environment Team</p>';
$MESSAGE_BODY .= 'email footer bits here ';
$MESSAGE_BODY .='<p style="color:#0C0;">Please consider the environment - do you really need to print this email?';
$MESSAGE_BODY_FINAL=wordwrap($MESSAGE_BODY,70);
$mailsent=  mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY_FINAL, $mailheader) or die ("Not Sent");
if($mailsent){
//update a table to record date email was sent
}
}
```